# Cannot get IIS pickup directory (From Windows Service)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, c#-3.0, iis-6

I am facing the above-mentioned error while sending emails from windows service. Your suggestion is much appreciated.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage mailMsg = this.ComposeMailMessage();
smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
```

*Configuration*

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="user1@mycompany.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="smtpsvr.mycompany.com" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: chances are, the process that runs your website doesn’t have access to the IIS metabase that stores the name of the pickup directory, and this is the general cause of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mine is not the answer you're searching, but try this (avoiding IIS):

```
try
{
    // To
    MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
    mailMsg.To.Add(to_Address);

    // From
    MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress(from_address);
    mailMsg.From = mailAddress;

    // Subject and Body
    mailMsg.Subject = subject;
    mailMsg.Body    = body;

    // Init SmtpClient and send
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtp_server, port);
    // System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
    //    new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtp_user, smtp_pwd);
    // smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;

    smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine( ex.Message );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the code inside the windows service is maintained by different party and it is working fine in some other environment.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the SmtpClient PickupDirectory manually.

There is an example of how to do that in the Lukas Pokorny's answer:

[Cannot get IIS pickup directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190361/cannot-get-iis-pickup-directory)

Comment: In fact, I want to use "network" as deliveryMethod since SMTP server is a separate server.

Answer (score 0):

Try add the following line to your program. This line needs the IIS Admin and SMTP service running on your desktop.

```
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
```

So it will become like this

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage mailMsg = this.ComposeMailMessage();
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
```