# IIS 7.5 SMTP Email from WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, smtp, email

I'm trying to use the SMTP Email Settings in IIS to send mail when a POST is made to a WCF Service.

In my service I create a MailMessage like so:

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        // Set the to and from addresses.
        // The from address must be your GMail account
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(GetWebConfigValue("emailTo")));
        mail.From = new MailAddress("mailer@me.com");

        // Define the message
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
        mail.Body = body;

        // Create a new Smpt Client using Google's servers
        var mailclient = new SmtpClient();
        mailclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
        mailclient.Send(mail);
```

However, it always breaks when it gets to the `DeliveryMethod` area stating: `SmtpExecption occurred: Cannot get IIS pickup directory.`

I was able to get it to work by manually defining the entries in the C# but my code needs to be a bit more configurable for multiple deployments.

I thought this approach might be a more seamless way to use IIS and this feature I needed.  Anyone got any thoughts / suggestions ?

[image: smptiis]

Comment: Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190361/cannot-get-iis-pickup-directory

Answer (score 0):

Needed to install service after configuring.  This gives the details:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ad9e940b-fe29-49fc-9bc4-6e572d505b2f/how-to-install-and-configure-smtp-server-in-windows-7